# How to check map values from each map in the RDD using scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I want to check map values from  each map in the RDD, MY quesn is

```
Let examples:RDD[Map[Int,String]]
```

ie.

```
examples = 
Map(0 -> sunny, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> FALSE, 4 -> no)
Map(0 -> sunny, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> TRUE, 4 -> no)
Map(0 -> overcast, 1 -> hot, 2 -> high, 3 -> FALSE, 4 -> yes)
Map(0 -> rainy, 1 -> mild, 2 -> high, 3 -> FALSE, 4 -> yes)
Map(0 -> rainy, 1 -> cool, 2 -> normal, 3 -> FALSE, 4 -> yes)
```

I want to check "value" in the last key-value pair of each Map.ie, here the last key-value pair in each Map is 4 -> no,4 -> no, 4 -> yes,..... From I need to check values in that key-value pair,ie. no,no,yes,yes,..... If all are "no" return no else return "yes".

Comment: There is no "last key-value pair" in a map (unless you're using a SortedMap. Do you know the maximum index will always be 4?

Comment: @Paul, we can find the last index from the number of columns.

Comment: Weird. Why not use a list, then? There's no need for a map if you know you have entries 0... size-of-map - 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
val examples = List(
  Map(0 -> "sunny", 1 -> "hot", 2 -> "high", 3 -> "FALSE", 4 -> "no"),
  Map(0 -> "sunny", 1 -> "hot", 2 -> "high", 3 -> "TRUE", 4 -> "no"),
  Map(0 -> "overcast", 1 -> "hot", 2 -> "high", 3 -> "FALSE", 4 -> "yes"),
  Map(0 -> "rainy", 1 -> "mild", 2 -> "high", 3 -> "FALSE", 4 -> "yes"),
  Map(0 -> "rainy", 1 -> "cool", 2 -> "normal", 3 -> "FALSE", 4 -> "yes"))

if (examples.forall(m => m(m.size - 1) == "yes")) 
  "yes"
else
  "no"
```

But this is horrible. Your choice of collection is suspect. If you have a `Map` where you know there are keys from `0 .. <some-upper-bound>` with no gaps, then you have an indexed sequence and not a `Map`, and you would find manipulating it easier if you used some `IndexedSequence` (e.g. a `List`, or a `Vector`).

Version that works on RDDs. Comments about choice of collection still apply

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-scratch").setMaster("local")
val sc= new SparkContext(conf)

val rdd  = sc.parallelize(examples, 1)

val yesno = rdd.map(m=>m(m.size - 1))
               .reduce ((l,r)=> if (l == "yes" && r == "yes") "yes" else "no")
```

Comment: My val examples is RDD[Map[Int,String]] not List[Map...]]. So here I can't use "forall"